# Python get Average

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a python module called gradebook and right now im on the class called Student  it has to have a name, id and the set of assessment that are used to compute a grade. The student name and id should be public the list of assessment have to be private. The list of the assessment are ESSAY and TEAM PROJECT. User should be able to add assessment to the list and user should be bale to obtain the student average via an operation get_average() (the average of all of the assessment) so far I have this:

```
class Student

def __init__(self, fname=' ', lname=' ',id=' ', grades= none):

   self.firstName = fname

   self.lastName  = lname

   self.id        = id

   if grades is none:

     self.gradeBook =[]

   else

     self.gradeBook = grades

studenList= []

def get_average
```

what do I need to add or delete to this to fulfill the Student class..

Comment: @barranka here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the average of a list can be easily achieved with the built-in functions `sum()` and `len()`:

```
def get_average(self):
    return sum(self.gradeBook, 0.0) / len(self.gradeBook)
```

Comment: how would I add assessment to the list of these?

Comment: Use the `append()` method of list: `self.gradeBook.append(new_grade)`.

Comment: but I need to add the assessment "essay" and "teamproject" how would I do that to this list @a.rodas

Comment: Then you need a dictionary instead of a list, so you can do `self.gradeBook["essay"] = essay_grade`.

Comment: so now that I do that for essay and team project. it then says users should be able to obtain the students average via an operation get_average(0 (average of all of the grades of the assessment) how would I calculate that into this @a.rodas

Comment: I tried all day to get this done I just don't know how add the assessment and get the average